# Why doesn't the different indentation of two functions' return statements produce different results?

Tags: python

I'm asked to write a Python function that determines if a list is sorted. I have two versions:

```
def is_sorted(t):
    for i in range(len(t) -1 ):
        if t[i] <= t[i + 1]:
            return True
        return False

def is_sorted(t):
    for i in range(len(t) -1 ):
        if t[i] <= t[i + 1]:
            return True
    return False
```

What's the difference between these two? I indented `return False` on the first one. However, they both yield the same results. Are there any subtile differences in them?

Comment: What data did you test these on??

Comment: No, the first one returns false only when the if condition is met for every loop. The second returns when the loop is completed.

Comment: Also importantly, neither of these come anywhere close to checking if a list is sorted. The first will return True if the first two elements are in increasing order, and False otherwise (it could be called `are_first_two_sorted`). The second will return True if *any* pair of consecutive elements is in increasing order (it could be called `is_not_sorted_backwards`).

Comment: While both do different things, neither will work. If the first and second numbers are sorted, both will return `True` regardless of the rest of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these does what you want. With the first, only the first two items will be compared, because you `return` in the first iteration of the loop regardless of whether the first two items are in order (although you return different results in these cases). The `for` loop doesn't really do anything. With the second, items will continue being compared only if they are out of order, because you return from the function the first time you see pair that is in order.

What you want is to return `False` immediately when items are out of order (since once you have found a pair of items out of order, you know the list is not sorted and don't need to check any further) and keep going only when pairs are *in* order, returning `True` only after you have inspected all items.  Like this:

```
def is_sorted(t):
    for i in range(len(t) - 1):
        if t[i] > t[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Or, using Python's built-in `all()` function with a generator expression:

```
def is_sorted(t):
    return all(t[i] <= t[i + 1] for i in range(len(t) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the effect of the indentation - i.e. what block your `return False` statement belongs to.

- In the former case, your function will return `False` the first time you have two elements ordered in *ascending* fashion.
- In the latter case your function will return `False` when *all* elements are sorted in ascending order.